# How can I change the background color for the active tab in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I know how to change the file colors in Appearance & Behavior, but how can I change the background color of the active tab? It's probably somewhere in the theme section, but how do I change that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

unfortunately it's not customizable. Please vote for [IDEA-126775](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126775) to increase its priority and be notified about updates.

Please also check this thread: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5532304#5532304 - you might find the suggestions helpful

Answer (score 2):

The [ActiveTabHighlighterPlugin](https://github.com/tobszarny/ActiveTabHighlighterPlugin/releases) now solves this problem.

It's compatible with: IntelliJ IDEA **PhpStorm** WebStorm PyCharm RubyMine AppCode CLion Gogland DataGrip Rider Android Studio.